# Pixel-wise weighted loss function in Keras - TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to write a pixel-wise weighted loss function for my model written in Keras but in TensorFlow 2.0 it seems that it is not possible anymore, i.e. it is not possible to have a loss function with other inputs than `y_true` and `y_pred`

I used to write it as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def my_keras_model():
  input = Input((256,256,1), name='input')
  weight = Input((256,256,1), name='weights')
  c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', padding='same')(input)
  outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c1)

  model=Model(input=[input,weight], output=outputs)
  model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001, name='adam'), loss=my_weighted_loss(weight))
  return model

def my_weighted_loss(weight):    
   def loss(y_true, y_pred):
     return K.mean(weight * K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
   return loss
```

Any idea of how to do it in TF 2?

Comment: One solution is to disable the eager mode: `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`.

Answer (score 1):

One "hacky" way of implementing this would be adding the original input to the output, and writing your own loss function. This way you can do

```
weight = y_true[...,0]
y_true = y_true[...,1:]
```

I would also love to hear a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to implement weight maps and do it computation inside the model.
Since it is binary cross_entropy

```
model=Model(inputs=[image,weight,mask], outputs=outputs)
```

Define your model in such a way that incase if your using tf dataset.

```
output_types=((tf.float32,tf.float32,tf.float32),tf.float32)
output_shapes=(([1024,1024,1],[1024,1024,1],[1024,1024,1]),[1024,1024,1])
```

Now compute the loss function inside the model

```
bce = y_true * K.log(y_pred+epsilon) + (1-y_true) * K.log(1-y_pred+epsilon) #you have values of y_true also
```

Here model output would be this **computed loss**.
Incase if you need a computation out of your model. Just use a Lambda layer for the weights.

```
weights_out=layers.Lambda(lambda x:x)(weights)
```

and then output this layer also from your model. So model would have 2 outputs to compute the loss in the form of a tuple and this way also pixelwise weighted loss can be calculated.

```
 model=Model(inputs=[image,weights,mask], outputs=[outputs,weighted_out])
```